# key+mouse click simultaneous (xdotool)

Tags: linux, xdotool

Is it possible to simulate a keystroke (`"N"`) and a mouse click simultaneous in linux?

I use `xdotool` on fedora linux distro

I didn't find nothing related to this possibility

**Later Edit :**

I found the following workaround. I post it as someone might have a similar problem.

Even if the key is not pressed simultaneous with the click you can have it already pressed using :

```
<pseudocode>
keydown [options] keystroke  - it will keep the key pressed.
Mouse click here.
keyup keystroke              - it will release the key
```

Comment: nice first post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In new versions you can do

```
xdotool keydown N click 1 keyup N
```

In older versions you can do as you edited:

```
xdotool keydown N
xdotool click 1
xdotool keyup N
```